# Detecting a specific date type in PHP string

Tags: php, regex-negation

Ok, i'm using a library to get some strings from X website, this string looks like:

Mar 17 2019, 16:08:43 CET Died at Level 418 by Gaz'haragoth.

```
if($player->getDeaths()) {
    $mystring = $player->getDeaths()[0];
    $dateString = preg_replace("/\([^)]+\)/","",$mystring);
    $date = new DateTime($dateString);
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

This is how my code looks looks like right now, how can I get only "Mar 17 2019, 16:08:43"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
echo substr("Mar 17 2019, 16:08:43 CET Died at Level 418 by Gaz'haragoth.", 0, 21);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use regex search of

```
(.*?)[0-9]+[:][0-9]+[:][0-9]+
```

on the string. Gets everything before the hh:mm:ss tag and nothing after

Getting substring upto a certain position too would work if it will be the same length every time.

Answer (score 0):

If the first half of the string (the date) is standard you can also use this without any regex needed:

`$output_str = implode(" ",array_splice(explode(" ",$input_str),0,4));`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateTime::createFromFormat` to create a DateTime object from that string.

```
$string = "Mar 17 2019, 16:08:43 CET Died at Level 418 by Gaz'haragoth.";

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('M d Y, H:i:s T+', $string);
```

Then you can output from that in whatever format you like.

You may not really need a DateTime object though. If all you need to do is strip off the trailing text it seems like `substr` would be the simplest way, as long as your day is formatted with a leading zero the date part of the string should always be the same length.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php
$str = "Mar 17 2019, 16:08:43 CET Died at Level 418 by Gaz'haragoth";
echo preg_replace('/^(.+\d+:\d+:\d+).+$/', '$1', $str);
?>
```